# PHP Scraping saves data running manually but not via CRON job

Tags: php, arrays, web-scraping, serialization, cron

I have a php script that loads saves daily market price data. It runs perfectly when running it manually but not via the CRON job. The CRON job does run and saves the data but not the serialized data from the array.

I suspect it has something to do with this

```
file_put_contents($filename, serialize($aDataTableDetailHTML)); // This only works when running the script manually through the cron job it saves a blank file "N;"

file_put_contents($filename, "test"); // This works perfectly manually and via the cron Job
```

Here is the full script.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');

function scrape_prices($html_address, $commodity)
{
    $htmlContent = file_get_contents($html_address);
        
    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
    $DOM->loadHTML($htmlContent);
    
    $Header = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('th');
    $Detail = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td');

    //#Get header name of the table
    foreach($Header as $NodeHeader) 
    {
        $aDataTableHeaderHTML[] = trim($NodeHeader->textContent);
    }
    //print_r($aDataTableHeaderHTML); die();

    //#Get row data/detail table without header name as key
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    foreach($Detail as $sNodeDetail) 
    {
        $aDataTableDetailHTML[$j][] = trim($sNodeDetail->textContent);
        $i = $i + 1;
        $j = $i % count($aDataTableHeaderHTML) == 0 ? $j + 1 : $j;
    }
    //print_r($aDataTableDetailHTML); die();
    
    //#Get row data/detail table with header name as key and outer array index as row number
    for($i = 0; $i < count($aDataTableDetailHTML); $i++)
    {
        for($j = 0; $j < count($aDataTableHeaderHTML); $j++)
        {
            $aTempData[$i][$aDataTableHeaderHTML[$j]] = $aDataTableDetailHTML[$i][$j];
        }
    }
    $aDataTableDetailHTML = $aTempData; unset($aTempData);

    $exportDateTime = date("Y-m-d");
    $dir = __DIR__ . '/';
    $filename = $dir . $commodity . '_prices_' . $exportDateTime . '.bin';

    file_put_contents($filename, serialize($aDataTableDetailHTML)); // This only works when running the script manually
    
    
    //file_put_contents($filename, "test"); // This works perfectly manually and via the cron Job
    //print_r($aDataTableDetailHTML); die();
}

scrape_prices("http://www.joburgmarket.co.za/dailyprices.php?commodity=222&containerall=2", "tomato");
//print_r(__DIR__);
//die();?>
```

Comment: `N;` is what you get if you serialize `null`, so it's most likely not the serialization that is the issue, but rather getting the data. Do some proper debugging to narrow the issue down, like logging the results of each step to a file and see where it goes bananas. When you say "run it manually", are you running it from the command line, or do you trigger it through the web server/browser?

Comment: "Manually" I mean entering the URL in the browser where the PHP script is saved. Then it works perfectly. only via the cron job it does not save the data

Comment: Since you're using CRON, I'm assuming your using Linux. On most linux dists, the web server and the CLI (which CRON is using) have two different php.ini files. Make sure that you have the same settings in both. Example: make sure [allow_url_fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) is enabled. Without it, `file_get_contents()` won't be able to load URL's. And also do as I suggested in the alst comment, do some debugging to narrow the issue down.